# Parse error in code: expected ' ; ' before ' { ' token -- what is causing this?

Tags: c++

The error I'm getting is `error: expected ' ; ' before ' { ' token`

I tried fixing the code by adding `;` after `if (thisisanumber==5)` as well as after `else (thisisanumber!=5)`. While this solves the first error it creates another error that says `error: ' else ' without a previous ' if '`. I'd really love to know what error I've made in writing the code, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int thisisanumber;

    cout<<"Whats the Password?: ";
    cin>> thisisanumber;
    cin.ignore();
    if (thisisanumber==5) {
        cout<<"You've discovered the password! Wow, you're a genious you should be proud./n";
        }
    else (thisisanumber!=5) {
        cout<<"You've failed in knowing the password and therefore cannot enter, leave and do not come back. Goodbye!/n";
        }
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Well, for a start, you declared main as returning an int, but I don't see a return statement anywhere.

Comment: @Slavik81 `main` implicitly returns 0 in C++.

Comment: Which line does the error point to? Also, an FYI unrelated to your question, a newline is \n not /n

Comment: As you're new here, I hope you informed yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need another condition as there are only two cases - just use `else { ... }` and it will catch all cases in which `thisisanumber==5` is `false`.

The structure of an `if` statement is:

```
if (condition) { ... }

else if (another condition) { ... }
// ... more conditions

else { ... all cases in which no previous condition matched end up here  ... }
```

... but the `else if` and `else` parts are always optional.

Comment: Note that `else if` is not a special language construct.  It's equivalent to `else { if(...) ... }`.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a keyword `if`:

```
else if (thisisanumber!=5) {
     ^^
```

Alternately, since the opposite condition to `thisisanumber == 5` is that `thisisanumber` is *not* 5, you don't need the condition:

```
else {
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens is the compiler looks at the following:

```
else (thisisanumber!=5) {
```

and thinks to itself:

"OK, here's `else`. Is the next token `if`? No. Ok, so this is an else clause, and the next thing is what to do in the else-case. Is the next token `{`? No. Ok, so in the else-case, we execute a single statement, instead of a block. Is the next token `(`? Yes. Ok, so our statement is wrapped in parentheses... [insert here: the rest of the thought process for interpreting an expression that's wrapped in parentheses] Ok, there's the matching `)`. Whew. Now let's just match up the `;` for this statement... wait, what's this? A `{`! That's not right."

The compiler is reading the code one token at a time, left to right. It does not report an error at the point where, in a logical sense that humans understand, the error actually is. It reports an error at the point where, by reading the code one token at a time, left to right, it is first able to detect that something is wrong.

It would be legal to write `else (thisisanumber!=5);`. That would mean "if the number is not equal to 5 (because the `if` test failed), then check if the number is not equal to 5, and do nothing with the result of that comparison". Meaningless, but legal. It would also be legal to write `else if (thisisanumber!=5) {...}`, which is presumably what you meant. That would mean "if the number is not equal to 5 (because the `if` test failed), and the number is not equal to 5, then do this stuff inside the `{}`". But this is redundant: given that something is not equal to 5, it is guaranteed to be not equal to 5, so there is no point in specifying the test twice. So we should just write `else {...}`.

"else" is really a shorter word for "otherwise", and has that purpose in C++ as well.